# Issues regarding frames per second in j2me

Tags: java-me

I'm developing a racing game. The speed is varying on different devices. I'm moving the background using a count to maintain constant speed.

But the speed is an issue. How to maintain a constant in all devices like nokia,samsung,etc. ?

I am using [java.util.Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Timer.html). Timer count duration varies in different devices.

Comment: are you using [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Timer.html "API javadocs")?

Comment: yes..am using a timer. Timer count duration varies in different devices.

Comment: This question is not specific to JavaME, and i think it better fits in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, here's a very good [article on the topic](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)